# Generic number validation

Tags: c#, generics, compareto

I've got a method like this:

```
public static bool IsPercentage<T>(T value) where T : IComparable
{
    return value.CompareTo(0) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(1) <= 0;
}
```

I would like to use this to validate if any number falls in the range 0 <= N <= 1. However this only works with integers since CompareTo only operates on equal types. Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: What types of objects do you expect this to work? Float, Double, Decimal and ...?

Comment: @ThomasW. Preferably any numeric type

Comment: @Servy I think it has nothing to do with the question you've set as *duplicate of*. OP doesn't need the method to only accept `T` as `int` (what's the point of having a generic method for only one type?!). He needs the `CompareTo` to get properly typed `0` and `1` value: `0`/`1` for `T==int`, `0d`/`1d` for `T==double`, etc.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Sounds like you only read the title, and didn't look at the actual question.

Comment: I read this from question: *I would like to use this to validate if any number falls in the range 0 <= N <= 1.* and from comments: *What types of objects do you expect this to work? Float, Double, Decimal and ...?* with *Preferably any numeric type* as a response.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I mean you didn't read the question that I proposed as a duplicate.  You just looked at the title.  If you clicked the link to see what it's really asking, you'd see it clearly answers this question.

Comment: It says: you can't set generic constraint to do this. But it doesn't actually mean you can't make the method work.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek There is no way to ensure that the method is only called with a type for which this will work.  Any solutions would, by necessity, have to do the checks at runtime, not compile time, and thus not be able to statically validate the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well you *could* use `Convert.ToDecimal`, then you don't need to be generic:

```
public static bool IsPercentage(Object value)
{
    decimal val = 0;
    try
    {
        val = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    return val >= 0m && val <= 1m;
}
```

Comment: This returns `true` for `1.1m`

Comment: @Servy {facepalm} thanks - changed to Decimal

Comment: Note that with this code there are certain float/double values that are just barely larger than one that, when converted to a decimal, are considered equal to one.  For example, call this method with `1f + float.Epsilon`.  It will return true, despite being greater than one.  The same applies to `1d + double.Epsilon`.

Comment: That's quite an inefficient function. You've got a boxing/unboxing action and a conversion for any non decimal type within an exception block. Given that there's only 3 types this method will be called with (float/double/decimal) this is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expression Tree to do this. Consider helper, static class

```
static class NumericHelper<T>
{
    public static T Zero { get; private set; }
    public static T One { get; private set; }

    static NumericHelper()
    {
        Zero = default(T);
        One = Expression.Lambda<Func<T>>(
                Expression.Convert(
                    Expression.Constant(1),
                    typeof(T)
                )
              ).Compile()();
    }
}
```

It generates `(T)1` cast at runtime and assign result to `One` property. Because static constructor is fired only once code necessary to generate properly typed `1` value will be executed only once for every `T`.

```
public static bool IsPercentage<T>(T value) where T : IComparable
{
    return value.CompareTo(NumericHelper<T>.Zero) >= 0 && value.CompareTo(NumericHelper<T>.One) <= 0;
}
```

Ofc, it will fail if you try to call it with type `T` which don't support `(T)1` conversion.